# Given n; check if it is formed by a number and its reverse

Tags: algorithm

Given `n`. Let's say there exists a number `x` and consider the reverse of digits of `x`, which is `y`. Now, `n = x + y`. Eg:`110(= 46+64)`My question is that how to check if there exists at least one way to represent given number as sum of some other number and its reverse of digits

Comment: How big is the number?

Comment: @giotskhada Sorry, I don't know the limits of the number. This is something I was asked to code during an interview. You can assume highest difficulty within solvable limits.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this brute-force and looking for more effective solution or are you just looking for any solutions? Cause, I can write out a brute-force O(nlogn) solution for you, but I'm not sure you need that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782075/c-sum-of-reverse-numbers/36782495

Comment: Can the reverse have leading zeros ?  In other words, is 101 = 100+001 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a simple, brute-force solution with time complexity `O(nlogn)`, which I'm assuming is good enough for an interview setting (although, for an actual contest, probably wouldn't be good enough). You could just iterate over every number up to `n` and check if `x` is a reverse of `n-x`. The check takes `logn` time (`log(10)n` to be precise, which is lower). Here's a pseudo-code:

```
isReverse(string a, string b) {
  if (a.length != b.length) return false;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] != b[a.length - i - 1]) return false;
  }
}

solution (n){
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (isReverse(i.toString(), (n-i).toString())) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the interview context: this problem is not a common problem with a well known algorithm (this is not KMP or Dijsktra's algorithm!), and I think there absolutely no reason for someone to expect an out of the box answer.

Even if you had the idea to try to compute the carrys, you can not be sure that it works until you see it work. There is, if I'm not mistaken, a solution with a time complexity O(log10 N). I focused on removing the carrys and built the algorithm (and the implementation) from scratch: there may remain subtle bugs in some edge cases. (The result is very close to the accepted answer of the [twin question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782075/c-sum-of-reverse-numbers/36782495).)

## Preliminary remarks

### Can every palindromic number be written as the sum of two mirror numbers?

The first idea that comes to mind is that such a number would be a palindrom:

```
  1 2 5
+ 5 2 1
-------
  6 4 6
```

But that's not true, since we know there are carry when the sum of two digits is greater or equal to 10.

Let's start with an easy question: can every palindromic number be written as the sum of two mirror numbers?

Imagine we have `N = D[2n]...D[n+1]D[n+1]...D[2n]` where `D[k]` is the k-th digit. Obviously, we can write:

```
  D[2n]-1 ... D[n+1]-1        1 ...       1
+       1 ...        1 D[n+1]-1 ... D[2n]-1
-------------------------------------------
    D[2n]       D[n+1]   D[n+1]       D[2n]
```

But what if the number of digits is odd? `N = D[2n]...D[n+1]D[n]D[n+1]...D[2n]`. We can write:

```
  D[2n]-1 ... D[n+1]-1 D[n]/2        1 ...       1
+       1 ...        1 D[n]/2 D[n+1]-1 ... D[2n]-1
--------------------------------------------------
    D[2n]       D[n+1]   D[n]   D[n+1]       D[2n]
```

But this is okay only if `D[n]` is even.

### What if the number is not a palindrom?

Could `927` be written as the sum of two mirror numbers? Imagine we have:

```
  a b c
+ c b a
-------
  9 2 7
```

There is no incoming carry for the unit digit, hence `c+a = 7` or `c+a = 17`. In both cases, the hundreds digits will be either `7` (no carry) or `8`. Units digit and hundreds digit are not close enough to allow the number to be written as the sum of two mirror numbers.

Let's be more specific.

Let `N = D[n+1]D[n]...D[0]` having `D[n+1] = 0 or 1` (if the first digit is not `1`, we add a `0` in front of the number).

Since the primary school, we know how to add two numbers `A[n]...A[0]` and `B[n]...B[0]`. The carrys are:

```
C[0] = 0
C[k+1] = (A[k] + B[k] + C[k]) // 10
```

And the digits are:

```
D[k] = (A[k] + B[k] + C[k]) % 10
D[n+1] = C[n+1])
```

If `N = A(n)...A(0) + A(0)...A(n) = M + N - M`, we can specialize the proposition above because `A[k] = A(k)` and `B[k] = A(n-k)`. We have:

```
C[0] = 0
C[k+1] = (A[k] + A[n-k] + C[k]) // 10       (I)
```

And:

```
D[k] = (A[k] + A[n-k] + C[k]) % 10
D[n+1] = C[n+1]
```

To make those formulas more useful, we can rewrite the digit formula in a less usual way:

```
A[k] + A[n-k] + C[k] = 10*C[k+1] + D[k]         (II)
```

And replace `k` by `n-k`:

```
A[n-k] + A[k] + C[n-k] = 10*C[n-k+1] + D[n-k]
```

Putting both formulas together, we have:

```
D[k] - D[n-k] = C[k] - C[n-k] - 10*(C[k+1] - C[n-k+1])      (III)
```

`N` is not necessarily a palindrom, but we still have a strong relationship between `D[k]` and `D[n-k]`.

### Sketch of the algorithm

The idea is to use this relationship to compute the carrys. We proceed from outside to inside to build the carrys. If a carry is not 0 or 1, then there is no solution.

If all carrys are 0 or 1, then we remove the carrys. If the remaining "number" is not palindromic or if there is an odd middle digit, there is no solution.

Else we can build a solution as above.

## Algorithm

We will use (I) and (III) to progress from `C[k+1]` and `C[n-k]` to `C[k]` and `C[n-k+1]`. If we can't progress, ie if a carry is not `0` or `1`, then the hypothesis N = A + (N - A) is false.

If the number of digits `n+2` is even, we stop when `k = n-k+1`.
Else, we stop when `k = n-k`.

### Case 1: `C[k+1] = 1 and C[n-k] = 0`

#### If `D[n-k] = 9`

We know that `A[k] + A[n-k] = 9` because we would need a carry `C[n-k] = 1` to reach 19. We have **`C[n-k+1] = 0`** (III). The proposition (III) gives us `C[k]`, but we already know it's **`C[k] = 1`** to have `C[k+1] = 1`.

#### If `D[n-k] <= 8`

We know that `A[k] + A[n-k] <= 8` or `A[k] + A[n-k] >= 10`. But we have a carry `C[k+1] = 1`: the only choice is `A[k] + A[n-k] >= 10` and thus **`C[n-k+1] = 1`**. We compute `C[k]` using (III): `D[k] - D[n-k] = C[k]`, that is **`C[k] = D[k] - D[n-k]`**.

### Case 2: `C[k+1] = 1 and C[n-k] = 1`

We have `A[k] + A[n-k] + C[k] >= 10`, thus `A[k] + A[n-k] >= 9` and `A[k] + A[n-k] + C[n-k] >= 10`: **`C[n-k+1] = 1`**. We compute `C[k]` using (III): **`C[k] = D[k] - D[n-k] + 1`**.

### Case 3: `C[k+1] = 0 and C[n-k] = 0`

#### If `D[n-k] = 9`

We know that `A[k] + A[n-k] = 9` because we would need a carry `C[n-k] = 1` to reach 19. Hence, **`C[n-k+1] = 0`** and **`C[k] = 0`**.

#### If `D[n-k] <= 8`

We know that `A[k] + A[n-k] <= 8` or `A[k] + A[n-k] >= 10`. But we have no carry (`C[k+1] = 0`): the only choice is `A[k] + A[n-k] <= 8` and thus **`C[n-k+1] = 0`**. We compute `C[k]` using (III): `D[k] - D[n-k] = C[k] + 10`, that is **`C[k] = D[k] - D[n-k]`**.

### Case 4: `C[k+1] = 0 and C[n-k] = 1`

#### If `D[n-k] = 9`

We know that `A[k] + A[n-k] = 8` or `A[k] + A[n-k] = 18`. But if `A[k] + A[n-k] = 18`, we would have `C[k+1] = 1`. Hence, `A[k] + A[n-k] = 8`, **`C[n-k+1] = 0`** and, using (III), `D[k] - D[n-k] = C[k] - 1`, that is **`C[k] = D[k] - D[n-k] + 1`**.

#### If `D[n-k] = 0`

We know that `A[k] + A[n-k] = 9` and **`C[n-k+1] = 1`**. Since `C[k+1] = 0`, we have **`C[k] = 0`**.

#### If `1 <= D[n-k] <= 8`

We know that `0 <= A[k] + A[n-k] <= 7` or `10 <= A[k] + A[n-k] <= 17`. Since `C[k+1] = 0`, we know that `0 <= A[k] + A[n-k] <= 7`. Hence we have **`C[n-k+1] = 0`** and **`C[k] = 0`**.

### Extract the solution

Use (II) to compute the `S(k) = A[k] + A[n-k]`:

```
A[k] + A[n-k] = D[k] - C[k] + 10*C[k+1]
```

`S(k)` may be greater than `9`, but the list: `[S(n), ..., S(0)]` have to be palindromic.

If the is an odd number of elements, then we need the middle element to be even. For the other elements:

- If `S(k) = 0`, then set `A[k] + A[n-k] = 0`
- If `1 <= S(k) <= 10`, then set `A[k] = S(k) - 1` and `A[n-k] = 1`
- If `10 <= S(k) <= 18`, then set `A[k] = S(k) - 9` and `A[n-k] = 9`

### Time complexity

The time complexity is `O(log10 N)` since we loop over the digits three times (could probably be one or two times).

## Implementation in Python

The implementation is full of edge cases. I tested it for numbers between 10 and 10000, but there may remain subtle bugs.

```
def check_mirror_sum(N):
    D = list(map(int, reversed(str(N))))
    if D[-1] > 1:
        D.append(0)
    n = len(D) - 2
    C = [None] * (n+2)
    C[n+1], C[0] = D[n+1], 0

    for k in range(n, 0, -1):
        if k - (n-k+1) < 0:
            break
        if C[k+1] == 1:
            if C[n-k] == 0:  # case 1
                if D[n-k] == 9:
                    e, f = 1, 0
                else:
                    f = 1
                    e = D[k] - D[n-k]
            else:  # C[n-k] == 1, case 2
                f = 1
                e = D[k] - D[n-k] + 1
        else:  # C[k+1] == 0
            if C[n-k] == 0:  # case 3
                if D[n-k] == 9:
                    e, f = 0, 0
                else:
                    f = 0
                    e = D[k] - D[n-k]
            else: # C[n-k] == 1, case 4
                if D[n-k] == 9:
                    f = 1
                    e = D[k] - D[n-k] + 1
                elif D[n-k] == 0:
                    e, f = 0, 1
                else:
                    e, f = 0, 0
        if not (0 <= e <= 1 and 0 <= f <= 1) or (k == n-k+1 and e != f):
            return None

        C[k], C[n-k+1] = e, f

    S = [D[k] - C[k] + 10*C[k+1] for k in range(n+1)]
    A = [None] * (n+1)
    if (n+1) % 2 == 1:
        if S[(n+1)//2] % 2 == 1: # odd middle "digit"
            return None

        A[(n+1)//2] = S[(n+1)//2] // 2
    for k in range((n+1)//2):
        if S[k] != S[n-k]: # not a palindrom! 
            return None
        if S[k] == 0:
            A[k], A[n-k] = 0, 0
        elif S[k] <= 10:
            A[k], A[n-k] = S[k] - 1, 1
        else:
            A[k], A[n-k] = S[k] - 9, 9
    if A[0] == 0 or A[-1] == 0: # should not start or end with 0
        return None

    M = int("".join(map(str, A)))
    return M
```

Test:

```
def control(N):
    for i in range(1, N):
        s = "".join(reversed(str(i)))
        if s[0] != '0' and i + int(s) == N:
            return i

    return None


for N in range(10, 10000):
    M = check_mirror_sum(N)
    M2 = control(N)
    assert (M is None) == (M2 is None)

    if M is not None:
        print("{} = {} + {}".format(N, M, N-M))
```

Output:

```
10 = 5 + 5
12 = 6 + 6
14 = 7 + 7
16 = 8 + 8
18 = 9 + 9
...
9779 = 8611 + 1168
9878 = 7891 + 1987
9889 = 8711 + 1178
9988 = 7991 + 1997
9999 = 8811 + 1188
```